# Please point out where I am going wrong

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

To use the wireless network in the airport you must pay
the daily fee unless you are a subscriber to the service.
Express your answer in terms ofw: “You can use the wireless
network in the airport,” d: “You pay the daily fee,”
and s: “You are a subscriber to the service.”

Daily fee is necessary to use the wireless network converts to

w-> d say this is X

So, original statement is X unless s
implies not(s) -> X i.e.
        not(s) -> w -> d  (replacing X)
implies [not(s) and w] -> d

Please help

Comment: The actual answer as I have seen is w-> (d or s)

Comment: I would stick to that .... the only question is wether to use an 'or' or a 'xor'.... but I think,  english is not  precise enough to determine that....

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get what you said Borge. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please edit to make your question title more specific to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

ok I will do this in detail, so I will post it as an answer.

when you say $\neg s \Rightarrow X$ with $X:=(w\Rightarrow d)$ that means that if s is not true then the statement X is true ... that is not what you wanted to say because the Statement should always be true....
by the way... when you substetude X back, don't forget the brackets.... they are important: $\neg s \Rightarrow (w\Rightarrow d)$ is equivalent with the above mentioned while $\neg s \Rightarrow w\Rightarrow d$ means if s is not true than w is true and if w is true then d is true. So this implies $\neg s \Rightarrow d$

What you want to say is that you can use the Network if (and only if) you are either a subscriber or pay the daily fee. So you would write $w\Leftrightarrow (d \vee s)$ where $\vee$ means 'or'

What I mentioned in the comment is: It is not clear wether you ***can*** pay a fee if you are a subscriber .... if you can the $\vee$ is correct.. if you can not then you would use an xor (exclusive or, $\veebar$) which means that you can either be subscriber or pay a daily fee

but there are very few languages wich do differ those two or's so you can't tell which one is ment... that is why we stick to mathematical notation ;)

Comment: Sorry Borge I am not understanding it. What I am trying to apply is just a mechanical process from what Rosen says in his book on discrete mathematics.

Comment: Also what you say here "you say ¬s⇒X¬s⇒X with X:=(w⇒d)X:=(w⇒d) that means that if s is not true then the statement X is true ..." is wrong. Like not(a) -> b doesn't mean a -> not (b)

Comment: First of all $\neg a\Rightarrow b$ does not  imply $a\Rightarrow \neg b$ but $\neg b \Rightarrow a$..... E.g if it rains the ground will be wett doesn't imply that the ground will not be wet if it doesn't rain......

Comment: Which part didn't you understand?